# Redirect from PHP page is it wasn't included or required

Tags: php, redirect, include, require

I have a set of PHP files that I am including and using as templates for information that I am storing in a MYSQL Database. These files can be accessed with the link to them. I do not want these files to be accessed if they are not being loaded by another file.

For example:
I have a file called `errorBox.php` which should only be visible when included in `mainPage.php`. However, currently, by going to `http://myUrl.com/errorBox.php` I can access the page.

I have tried using the following:

```
header("Location: http://myUrl.com");
```

but unfortunately it doesn't seem to work.

Is there a way to redirect automatically from these pages if they have not been included? Or is there a different solution to my problem?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Define a Variable in the main page. In the included page look this variable up. if the variable is not defined and correctly set, redirect

Comment: Thank you, I will try this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May you can check if was included/required using the [get_included_files](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-included-files.php) function.

And if was not included/required, you can redirect:

```
header('Location: http://myurl.com');
die;
```

Use `die` after to stop execute things.